# How to use RElasticSearch package to execute a query that runs on ElasticSearch head?

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I am working on RElasticSearch package. I ran a GET query in ElasticSearch-head on my index which looks like this:

```
{
  "query": {
     "term": {
      "id": "0a88d2dd43fe985501440bbd6610768f"
    }
  }
}
```

This ran successfully. I want to know how to specify this query in searchES method of RElasticSearch package. I tried finding answers but there is no proper documentation anywhere. Can anyone please help me out?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never mind. I used the POST method in httr package in R and passed my JSON object as a string parameter. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I used the POST method in httr package in R and passed my JSON object as a string parameter. It worked.

Something like :

library(httr)
filter<-'{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"createdTime":{"from":"2014-03-07","to":"2014-03-07"}}}]}}}'
POST("//_search?pretty",body=filter)

Comment: You may want to check out another R client for Elasticsearch in development I'm working on called `elastic` https://github.com/ropensci/elastic